# Docker container exit code Issue in java process spring batch and aws batch

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I am running my docker container on AWS batch. There is some error scenario where java -jar process ends with non zero exit code but docker exits with 0 as status code that is making AWS batch to show that job successfully completed.

Can anyone help me in this scenario how can I make docker exits with same status code as that of java process.

My java app is written in spring batch and on running locally I have verified that the java process is exiting with non zero status code.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8u212-jre-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat && ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

WORKDIR /usr/local/orgname

VOLUME /usr/local/orgname/logs

ADD build/libs/jarname.jar /usr/local/orgname/
ADD entrypoint.sh /usr/local/orgname/
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/orgname/entrypoint.sh
RUN apk update && apk add curl bash

CMD ["/usr/local/orgname/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 8443
```

entrypoint.sh :

```
exec java -Dsun.net.inetaddr.negative.ttl=0 \
 -jar "jarname.jar" \
 --server.ssl.key-alias=$JKS_KEY_ALIAS \
 --server.ssl.key-store-password=$JKS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD \
 --server.ssl.key-password=$JKS_KEYSTORE_KEY_PASSWORD \
 --server.ssl.key-store=$JKS_FILE \
 --server.ssl.key-store-type=jks &
wait
```

Comment: Can you include some details? The `Dockerfile`, frameworks you're using in the Java app, what you've tried, etc. Without any of those, all we can do is guess.

Comment: @kichik Added the details.

Comment: Try removing `wait` and remove `&` from your entry point script.